# Showing the in-mail add-in bar in Outlook

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, office365-apps

Feel kinda silly for having to ask, but anyway... I seem to be missing the add-in toolbar shown inside of an e-mail which for instance contains the button to watch an address in Bing maps. The entire bar is missing. I tried finding an option to view it, that doesn't seem to exist (so it cannot be disabled either :)). Also tried making my O365 the only Outlook account since I have a corporate account where add-ins are not enabled.

To be clear; it's the bar as shown in this video by Jeremy Thake: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDBMI9OcqBQ, the entire bar is missing in both Office 365 OWA and the desktop client, from multiple PC's. Other add-in stuff does work, like the Boomerang add-in pane in an e-mail. I sent myself some e-mails with addresses in them (including the sample ones) to be sure it should trigger, but nothing happens. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

From the desktop Outlook client, click File -> Info -> Manage Add-ins.  It will launch the Manage add-ins page in the Outlook Web Application (or click the gears icon in OWA and choose "Manage add-ins").  Do you see the Bing Maps add-in listed?  If not, click the + icon and select "Add from the Office Store" and look for the Bing Maps add-in.

[image]

Comment: It's listed and enabled, amongst some others.

Comment: I think the problem may be with the Addin itself; I know from experience it doesn't work well with Canadian addresses